# Is it possible to set a background image on an SVG element with CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible to target a `background-image` SVG with CSS?

```
.color {
   background-color: #fff;
   color: #fff;
}

.svg {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 96 43'><path class='color' d='M 55.584673,43.175632 36.75281,22.967243 0,43.175632 40.42403,0 59.71135,20.208389 96,0 Z' /></svg>");
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you need to make sure that you will not break CSS syntax e.g. by unquoted symbol. You can also use base64 encoding for image

Comment: Can you show me an example? I tried doing this earlier and it seemed to not work.

Comment: @Flying, answers go down there.

Comment: It is not possible to target a background-image with CSS unless you put the CSS in the backgound image itself.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine as you can see below. But you may encounter problems in a case if your SVG will contain same quotes that you're using to place SVG image inside `url()`. They need to be either quoted like `\"` or replaced. You can also consider encoding your SVG image using base64 encoding, but it will make your CSS size bigger.

```css
svg {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.color {
   fill: blue;
}

.svg-plain {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 96 43'><path class='color' d='M 55.584673,43.175632 36.75281,22.967243 0,43.175632 40.42403,0 59.71135,20.208389 96,0 Z' /></svg>");
}

.svg-base64 {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnIHZpZXdCb3g9JzAgMCA5NiA0Myc+PHBhdGggY2xhc3M9J2NvbG9yJyBkPSdNIDU1LjU4NDY3Myw0My4xNzU2MzIgMzYuNzUyODEsMjIuOTY3MjQzIDAsNDMuMTc1NjMyIDQwLjQyNDAzLDAgNTkuNzExMzUsMjAuMjA4Mzg5IDk2LDAgWicgLz48L3N2Zz4=")
}

.svg, svg {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg svg-plain"></div>
<div class="svg svg-base64"></div>
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 96 43'><path class='color' d='M 55.584673,43.175632 36.75281,22.967243 0,43.175632 40.42403,0 59.71135,20.208389 96,0 Z' /></svg>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing what I want it to do. I want the actual SVG paths to be coloured, not just a background.

Comment: @Karai17 sorry, your question was not clear enough... It is also possible, but in this case you need to either embed your CSS directly into SVG (if you're inserting is as `<img>` or `<object>`) or you need to insert SVG directly into document as part of HTML page

Comment: So there is no way to style the SVG if it is a background image?

Comment: No, because in this case it is treated as image and not something that have its own internal structure